# IF ... THEN structure and how to apply across multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I have a dataframe containing 3 columns : `Postcode`, `Borough` and `Neighbourhood` with 257 rows. You can forget about `Postcode` for the moment.

[image]

- For `Borough` and `Neighbourhood`, either column could have a valid location already added or be `Not assigned` and I am trying to figure out how to do the following. **If a cell has a valid Borough location (can be anything) and the Neighbourhood is "Not assigned" then the Neighborhood will be set to equal the same as the Borough.**

So the logic would be something like this:

```
 If Neighbourhood="Not Assigned" AND Borough<>"Not Assigned" then Neighbourhood=Borough
    Repeat for all rows
```

Comment: Can you provide your python code? In python `IF ... THEN` is just `if ... :` .

Comment: Please avoid pointing out that you are a beginner and other phrases that are not relevant information to your problem since they are only distraction, for example we are not interested if you are a beginner or expert but the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas` library, we can use subsetting technique for a `DataFrame`.

Firstly, for testing purpose, I recreate the data frame with only 2 columns: `Borough` and `Neighbourhood`. I also add another row, since none of the provided data meet the condition.

```
borough = ["Not assigned", "Not assigned", "Not assigned", "Not assigned", "Etobicoke", "Etobicoke", "Etobicoke", "Etobicoke", "Etobicoke", "Not assigned", "Etobicoke"]
neighbourhood = ["Not assigned", "Not assigned", "Not assigned", "Not assigned", "Kingsway Park South West", "Mimico NW", "The Queensway West", "Royal York South West", "South of Bloor", "Not assigned", "Not assigned"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Borough": borough,
                   "Neighbourhood": neighbourhood})
print(df)
```

Then we create the conditional statement of: **If a cell has a valid Borough location (can be anything) and the Neighbourhood is "Not assigned" then the Neighborhood will be set to equal the same as the Borough.**

```
condition = (df["Borough"] != "Not assigned") & (df["Neighbourhood"] == "Not assigned")
print(condition)
```

`condition` is a `boolean Series` which contains only `True` and `False`, useful for subsetting the dataframe.

Lastly, we replace the value in `Neighbourhood` column with the value in `Borough` column if the row met the `condition`.

```
df.loc[condition, "Neighbourhood"] = df.loc[condition, "Borough"]
print(df)
```

**Alternatively**, you can also do looping, but it's not a good practice since the computation could be slower for bigger data:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    condition = (row["Borough"] != "Not assigned") & (row["Neighbourhood"] == "Not assigned")
    if condition:
        row["Neighbourhood"] = row["Borough"]
```